# How to add extra columns for a model if in particular category in Django + Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql

I need to add extra columns if product is in a particular category. I thought of using `JSON` or allowing null columns, but is there any better way of handling this situation. I'm using Postgresql database. Here are my model structure.

```
class Product(Base):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, validators=[validate_alphanumeric])
    is_safari = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Product table has mapped to agents like this

```
class Agent(Base):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.agent_user.username
    agent_user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
    )
    country = CountryField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

`AgentProduct` model

```
class AgentProduct(Base):
   
    agent = models.ForeignKey(
        Agent,
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
    )
    a_rate = models.IntegerField()
    c_rate = models.IntegerField()
```

I would like to add some extra information if `is_safari` is true to the `AgentProduct` model like

```
per_v_charge = models.IntegerField()
extra_p_charge = models.IntegerField()
# something like this
```

Comment: if you plan to store information, then I do not think there is any alternate to JSON or empty columns. I would prefer JSON

Comment: @ruddra if we have searching or mathematical calculations JSON will be slow?

Comment: It could be slow but I am not sure what use cases you might have here.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add nullable fields first.
2. Wait for A. need to add more and more nullable columns and B. building more and more queries using these nullable fields.
3. Based on gathered evidence of data and use cases, evaluate what is best, whether keeping them as nullable columns or adding a JSON field.

Two categories for making the desition come in form what is best for you and for the app:

Evaluating what is best for you is to define what is easy to read and understand to other developers; usually, the solution with less code and easier to document is likely better all the time.

To evaluate what is best for the app is to define what is heavy for Django or postgres to handle, nowadays postgres handles very well JSON fields and Django supports them as if they were important for the ORM. Still, once again, you have to throw consistent schemas for it to be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongoDb for schemaless database structure. You can create different "columns" for different "rows" with it.

Comment: Just for a single table moving into mongo is not a solution for me. I thought of this as well but from my experiences django Postgres combo worked well in the past. For a fresh project this solution can be considered I think.